# Может ли быть Array в квадрате?

Tags: javascript

Знаю, странное название, но интересно, каким образом нужно сделать, так чтобы отобразился только 1 текст, без других текстов и символов.

```js
const customElement = document.createElement(tag = 'input', properties = [['innerHTML', 'Lorem Ipsum'], ['type', 'text'], ["placeholder", "dolor lorem"]], styles = [['color', 'red'], ['fontSize', '24px']], parentEl = document.querySelector(".Rock"));
console.log(properties[1]);
```

При введении console.log получаю *[ "type", "text" ]*, а хочется чтобы допустить вывело *"type"*. Каким образом можно это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `console.log(properties[1][0])` - это не массив в квадрате, а вложенный массив.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Простите, а что это за createElement такой?